# How do you get the encoding of the terminal from within a python script?

Tags: python, encoding, terminal

Let's say you want to start a python script with some parameters like

```
python myscript some arguments
```

I understand, that the strings `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` will have the encoding specified in the terminal. Is there a way to get this information from within the python script?

My goal is something like this:

```
terminal_enocding = some_way.to.GET_TERMINAL_ENCODING
some = `sys.argv[1]`.decode(terminal_encoding)
arguments = `sys.argv[2]`.decode(terminal_encoding)
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`sys.stdout.encoding` will give you the encoding of standard output. `sys.stdin.encoding` will give you the encdoing for standard input.

Answer (score 9):

You can call `locale.getdefaultlocale()` and use the second part of the tuple.

See more [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/PythonEncodingUsesSystemLocale) (Fedora wiki entry explaining the why's and how's of the default encoding in Python)

Answer (score 1):

The function `locale.getpreferredencoding()` also seems to do the job.

It returns the Python encoding string which you can directly use like this:

```py
>>> import locale
>>> s = b'123\n'
>>> enc = locale.getpreferredencoding()
>>> s.decode(enc)
'123\n'
```