# pymysql is not recognizing ® (the registered trademark symbol) on PuTTY

Tags: python, sql, putty, pymysql

If I try to run a python file with this line in it:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT GameName FROM GamesTable WHERE GameName = 'Sid Meier's Civilization® IV'")
```

PuTTY gives me the error:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, u"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's
Civilization\xae IV'' at line 1")
```

So it clearly can't read the ® symbol.

I've searched around and people said to be sure that the Remote Character Set is UTF-8, which it is.

Also, PuTTY seems to handle the symbol fine - if I just write `print "®"` then it correctly prints the symbol. It is only when trying to use pymysql to reach the sql server that it seems to have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unicode error ? (assuming python 2)

gname = "Sid Meier's Civilization" + unichr(174) + "IV'"

then

gname.encode('utf-8')

which gives
"Sid Meier's Civilization\xc2\xae IV"

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but to be clear python can read it just fine. Like if I make the whole python script just "print ®" then it does show ® in Putty.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain that properly its the terminal encoding cuasing that as you haven't set it.  So mystring.encode('utf-8' )http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396659/how-do-you-get-the-encoding-of-the-terminal-from-within-a-python-script